# Execute Javascript before Page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having an issue with  [Mysite](http://www.what4electronics.co.za), the navigation bar is javascript and bits of jquery, I've played around with some code to try and get the navigation bar to load before page view but cant seem to find the right code.What would be the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 2):

The script will execute whenver the page loads

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload=body_load;

    function body_load()
    {

    dosomethingwithelementA();

    }

    </script>

    <div id="A"></div>
```

OR u do with jquery whenever the dom is ready

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    dosomethingwithelementA();

});
```

Comment: I believe the question was not how to postpone JS execution until after the entire page was loaded, but how to actually prevent the page from loading until JS has interacted with the navigation elements. This code doesn't do any of those things

Comment: Thanks for this, However Elias Is quiet right. I want the page to wait until the JS has loaded.Then after JS has loaded call the body of the page.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things that can help:

1. Put the `<script>` tags just below your navigation elements, and in case of the jQuery code, don't use the `$(document).ready(function(){` wrapper, BC that'll postpone the execution for as long as it takes for the page to load.
   Alternatively, instead of waiting for the entire document to be ready, there really is nothing to stop you from doing something like `$('#navContainer').ready(function(){`, to execute the jQuery bit as soon as the navigation elements have been loaded.
2. That said, you can't really determine what loads when, that's somewhat out of your hands. I have, however, seen people rendering HTML with an attribute like `style="display:none;"`, and then use JavaScript to remove the attribute when they've done what needs to be done/seen first. Downside: as always: JS-disabled browsers get to see no content at all. Ah, well, screw them
3. There are more elaborate answers, too. For instance: provide your pages with an empty content div, and only the navigation and bind the `onload` or `$(doc).ready` event to an ajax call to fetch the actual content of your site. But that is, IMO, a borderline insane workaround.

Pick and choose any of the above options, or use all of them together

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know theres no way to really load HTML before the Page starts. You should use JQUERY Events to wait with displaying the toolbar until it is loaded. Or maybe just set"display:none" to your toolbar, then use window.onload event to display the toolbar after adding all the Effects.

Answer (score -3):

Move the inclusion of your script into the `<head></head>`, that may help. But still, the DOM has to be loaded before any JS is fired.

Comment: DOM does **not** have to be loaded before javascript executes. DOM **does** have to be loaded before javascript can interact with it, but that is not equivalent with no execution at all.

Comment: He is trying to jqueryfy his menu - how is that supposed to work without the DOM ready?